# I need a text editor that does not use iframes

Tags: javascript

Need a good rich text editor like CKEditor, only one that does not use an iframe to hold the content.

The reason for not holding an iframe is that most modern browsers dont allow you to directly access elements within an iframe using javascript such as jquery.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914510/wysiwyg-editor-without-iframe

Comment: HUH? You can access iframes, if you could not, than the editors would not work.

Comment: They let you access it indirectly, which is trivial, so what's the big deal?

Answer (score 4):

http://nicedit.com/

Comment: Why the down-vote? NicEdit doesn't use iframes, as per this: http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/20/wysiwyg-choices-nicedit-vs-tinymce/

Answer (score -3):

Browsers only stop you accessing the contents of an iframe, if the iframe's content is [on a different domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). What other errors are you seeing?